# karate - Parsing runtime integer value coming from response of SOAP 1 to request of SOAP 2

Tags: soap, karate

Question is as follows:-

I have a two SOAP request , I am getting response from SOAP 1 in the form of integer at runtime. I want to parse that value to another soap request in three places to process the soap.

So far I have tried following things

1. I have taken the response of the first soap and took the value I wanted into one variable and printed it to make sure variable is receiving correct value.
2. In second soap request, I have re-defined the variable and set parameter of 2nd soap request = to the variable of 1st soap.

I am getting following error message

'no var found with name: response'

and if I directly put #(variable) name in parameter of the soap then I get following error message
'variable name can not be parsed as Int32'

Also I tried to parse the string into integer using groovy in feature fie but that didn't worked out.

Can someone please help me out with correct resolution to get the parse the runtime integer value of one soap into multiple places in soap 2?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2 patterns you can use:

Using embedded expressions:

```
* def myInt = 5
* def payload = <foo>#(myInt)</foo>
```

Using `set`

```
* def myInt = 5
* def payload = <foo></foo>
* set payload/foo = myInt
```

Don't forget to refer to the documentation. Also refer to this set of tests for more ideas: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)